# regarding regexp in PHP

Tags: php, regex, screen-scraping

I'm decent at PHP(far from an expert) but a pure novice when it comes to regexp and scraping. I wanted to do a little bit of scraping to help with some research and to educate myself, but I've ran into a problem. I want to extract prize from the following part of a page:

```
<th valign="top"> Prize pool:
</th>
<td> $75,000
</td></tr>
```

Needless to say, the prize pool value will change. I want to get the prize, and only the prize from this part (in this example the script should print out $75,000).

This is what I have so far:

```
preg_match('/Prize pool:\n<\/th>\n<td>(.*)/i', $file_string, $prize);
```

However, this prints out:

```
Prize pool:
</th> 
<td> $75,000
```

Comment: While @JohnConde's comment is quite true, a better answer here is that you should use something like http://php.net/domdocument.

Comment: put `//th[contains(text(), 'Prize pool')]/td` into https://gist.github.com/1358174

Comment: If the value is always going to be a dollar sign followed by numbers, could you not just search for the dollar and any numbers / commas after?

Comment: @gordon, maybe you meant: `//th[contains(text(), 'Prize pool')]/following-sibling::td` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/Prize pool:.+(\$\d+(?:\.|,)\d+)/is', $file_string, $prize);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($prize, 1) . '</pre>';
```

Like this.

A little explanation

`.` - to search for any single character, but not new line char "\n"

`+` - means one or more repetitions

So, `.+` means that after "Prize pool:" must be  more than one any char

`(...)` It is called a pocket. Each pocket in regex will be located in a each element of array (`$prize`)

`$` in patter means as end of line, therefore we need conversion it in single char by escaping it like this `\$`

`\d` - means one number from 0 to 9. And \d+ one or more numbers

`(?:...)` this is pocket too, but it not will be saved in $prize, because we used `?:` after `(`

As we know `.` is any single char, therefore for conversion it to dot we need escape it as `\.`, `\.|,` means we looking `.` or `,`

`/here pattern/i` modificator `i` here means, that regex will be no case insensitive

`/here pattern/s` modificator `s` means that metacharacter `.` will include char of new line.

Answer (score 0):

`Prize pool:\s*<\/th>\s*<td>\s+(.*)\s+<\/td>`

If you want to parse HTML to get this value only, just use regex; No need to use full HTML parser to capture a number from html string.

Use [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) to test you regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
$reg = '~Prize pool:.*?td>\s*(.*?)\s*<~';
```

[rubular demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/Vn1QiHZ1jT)